# TypeScript - `redis` module is undefined when running output file

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

I switched a Discord bot project from JavaScript to TypeScript.

But then running the compiled code (using `tcs`), the `redis` module is `undefined`. The compilation process success, other modules (`discord.js`, `dotenv`, etc) are imported and used just fine, requiring the `redis` module work but output a `undefined`.

My `tsconfig.json` (based on [@tsconfig/node16](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node16.json)):

```json
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDir": "./src/",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "sourceMap": false,
        "baseUrl": "./"
    },
    "files": [
        "src/index.ts"
    ],
    "include": [
        "./**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

I have tried many things including removing `typeRoots` and `exclude`.

My `package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "discord-bot",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "A bot to manage roles and such on Discord",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "tsc && node dist/index.js",
        "build": "tsc",
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@tsconfig/node16": "^16.1.0",
        "@types/node": "^16.9.0",
        "discord.js": "^14.11.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
        "redis": "^4.6.7",
        "typescript": "^5.1.6"
    }
}
```

All dependencies have been updated to latest and support NodeJS 16.

The start of my code:

```js
import Discord from "discord.js"
import redis from "redis"
import http from "http"
import "dotenv/config"
import * as process from "process"

// Initialise Discord Client
const discordClient: Discord.Client<true> = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations
    ]
})

// Create the database client
const redisClient = redis.createClient()
```

I am getting a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createClient')` at runtime at the last line, even if the compilation work fine and my IDE autocompleting the library functions properly.

(please note that I am still a beginner in TypeScript in Node contexts, coming from React TypeScript with frameworks)

Comment: That looks correct to me but I normally see folks just importing createClient directly using `import { createClient } from 'redis'`. Does that change anything?

Comment: That's really strange, but using this syntax make the script work fine.
I didn't change the syntax used for importing the module when migrating to TypeScript, so it was working in pure JS. I have also no idea why the compilation would work then and the IDE autocomplete too. I just checked the node-redis source code and it seems to not have a default export?? https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/index.ts
Its also annoying IMO to not beeing able to prefix the `createClient` function with `redis` since its a pretty common name and create confusion inside the file.

Comment: @AFCMS if you want to prefix with `redis` you could try importing like this: `import * as redis from "redis"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base on their [redis documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#user-content-usage) this is how I see on their snippet

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient();

client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

await client.connect();

await client.set('key', 'value');
const value = await client.get('key');
await client.disconnect();
```

upon checking on their type definition from `node_modules/redis/dist/index.d.ts` there are no default export that I found, so try to use the named export or create all alias for them `import * as redis from 'redis'`